# how to add a roll over state to the overlays

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have added an overlay to the map and changed colors of the overlay. I was wondering is it possible to add a hover event to the overlays? basically to when you hover over a US state if is is colored blue it will change to green. stuff like that. This is what i have right now.

http://www.opsdivina.net/soum/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work!

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon,"mouseover",function(){
this.setOptions({fillColor: "#00FF00"});
tooltip.style.visibility = 'visible';
}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon,"mouseout",function(){
this.setOptions({fillColor: "#FF0000"});
tooltip.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

The following links will help!
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_mouseover.htm, http://philmap.000space.com/gmap-api/poly-hov.html, http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_hoverchange75.htm

Comment: hi..hanks for this...i have been going through the examples and i think the 2nd one works really well...thanks again for your support

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/kml-support-getting-started/browse_thread/thread/66e7a7ab1b269104/d050e85ab54679a1

For some reason the quote below isn't formatting directly and skipping some of the xml so you want to just go to the link listed above for exact solution.  Tried to format it correctly here.

> If you want to highlight a polygon upon mouse-over you need to add a 
>   StyleMap to the feature with that polygon geometry.
>
> Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
    <Document> 
        <Style id="sn_style"> 
          <PolyStyle> 
            <color>00ff8080</color> 
            <fill>0</fill> 
          </PolyStyle> 
        </Style> 


        <Style id="sh_style"> 
          <PolyStyle> 
            <color>7fff8080</color> 
          </PolyStyle> 
        </Style> 


        <StyleMap id="msn_style"> 
            <Pair> 
                <key>normal</key> 
                <styleUrl>#sn_style</styleUrl> 
            </Pair> 
            <Pair> 
                <key>highlight</key> 
                <styleUrl>#sh_style</styleUrl> 
            </Pair> 
        </StyleMap> 


      <Placemark> 
        <name>Polygon with fade in/out</name> 
        <styleUrl>#msn_style</styleUrl> 
        <Polygon> 
          <outerBoundaryIs> 
            <LinearRing> 
              <coordinates> 
                138.64,-34.93 138.64,-34.94 138.63,-34.94 138.62,-34.94 
                138.62,-34.95 138.62,-34.96 138.61,-34.97 138.60,-34.97 
                138.59,-34.97 138.58,-34.97 138.57,-34.97 138.57,-34.96 
                138.57,-34.95 138.57,-34.94 138.57,-34.93 138.57,-34.92 
                138.57,-34.91 138.56,-34.91 138.56,-34.90 138.57,-34.90 
                138.57,-34.89 138.56,-34.88 138.57,-34.88 138.58,-34.87 
                138.58,-34.86 138.58,-34.85 138.60,-34.85 138.61,-34.85 
                138.63,-34.85 138.64,-34.86 138.64,-34.87 138.63,-34.87 
                138.63,-34.88 138.62,-34.88 138.62,-34.89 138.63,-34.89 
                138.63,-34.90 138.64,-34.90 138.64,-34.91 138.64,-34.92 
    138.64,-34.93 
              </coordinates> 
            </LinearRing> 
          </outerBoundaryIs> 
        </Polygon> 
      </Placemark> 
    </Document> 
    </kml>
```

> You can also combine technique that with a Region to only show when 
>   polygon is "active" in user's view.  Examples at
>   http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Region/
>
> Related references: 
>   http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#stylemap
>   http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#region

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried to follow your method man. here is the link. http://www.opsdivina.net/soum/index2.html maybe i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hover states in KMZ and KML does not work in V3. the only way to really accomplish this would be to call the polygon directly in the scripting. Doing that would allow you to add the listener inline.